# Click Link add a class on an adjacent element

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-selectors

There's a lot of examples on here that do something similar, but nothing I've done so far seems to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.check').on('click', function() {
        var element = $(this).next('.photo');
        $(element).toggleClass('selected');
    });
</script>
```

Here's the html:

```
<div class="box">
    <a class="check" href="#"></a>
    <img class="photo" src="/image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a class="check" href="#"></a>
    <img class="photo" src="/image.jpg">
</div>
<div class="box">
    <a class="check" href="#"></a>
    <img class="photo" src="/image.jpg">
</div>
```

and so on.

What I'm trying to do, is when you click the a tag, it will add a class to the image inside the same div as itself. I want the ability to have multiple images "selected". not just one.

Comment: Add the script in dom ready handler and try `jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.check').on('click', function () {
        var element = $(this).next('.photo');
        $(element).toggleClass('selected');
    });
})`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4z8qp/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny He just given a sample scenario, and he asks for if the scenario becomes like multiple image tags appended after that anchor tag..

Comment: @Arun P Johny That did it, I'm new to js so thanks for pointing that out. I'm also new to stackoverflow, or I'd up yours as an answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [**`.nextAll()`**](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) to select all the elements which are next to the current element with the supplied selector,

Try,

```
var element = $(this).nextAll('.photo');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.check').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings('img').toggleClass('selected');
});
```

This grabs the `img` [siblings()](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of the clicked anchor and toggles their `selected` class.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for what you're trying to do.

```
$('.check').click(function()
{
    $(this).find('.photo').toggleClass('selected');
});
```